# React Native Reanimated undefined is not a constructor Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have a code that will move the box up a bit when clicked on the 4th box, but I'm in trouble with the error I get, I keep getting the same error, error message = ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNativeReanimated.Value(0)')

This error is located at:`your text`
in AnimatedProductList
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in mosquitosrep(RootComponent)
ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNativeReanimated.Value(0)')

This error is located at:
in AnimatedProductList
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in mosquitosrep(RootComponent)

Methods I tried and it didn't work:
cd android & gradlew clean
remove node_modules and npm i
hermes to false
npm start --reset-cache

my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { Easing, timing, Value } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const AnimatedProductList = () => {
  const translateY = new Value(0);
  const animationDuration = 3000; // 3 seconds

  const startAnimation = () => {
    // Move the square 10 pixels up
    timing(translateY, {
      toValue: -10,
      duration: animationDuration / 2,
      easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
    }).start(() => {
      // After the first animation, return the square to its original position
      timing(translateY, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: animationDuration / 2,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
      }).start();
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.productBox}>
        <Text style={styles.productName}>Product 1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.productBox}>
        <Text style={styles.productName}>Product 2</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.productBox}>
        <Text style={styles.productName}>Product 3</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={startAnimation}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.animatedContainer,
            {
              transform: [{ translateY }],
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Text style={styles.productName}>Animated Product</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    padding: 15,
  },
  productBox: {
    width: width / 2.2,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  productName: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  animatedContainer: {
    width: width / 2.2,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default AnimatedProductList;
```

my reanimated version 3.4.2(last version)
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.72.4

I can't use the reanimated module please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `'react-native-reanimated/plugin'` to `babel.config.js` like this (as mentioned [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/#step-2-add-reanimateds-babel-plugin)):

```
  module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ... // don't add it here :)
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
```

after that run `npm cache clean –force && rm -rf node_modules && npm i && cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && npm start -- --reset-cache && npm run android`